# WPF Fullscreen in RibbonWindow

Tags: wpf, fullscreen, ribbon

I created an application using Microsoft ribbon for WPF. I used RibbonWindow instead of simple Window to place QuickAccessToolbar to window header.

The problem is that normal Window becomes fullscreen when i set

```
  WindowStyle="None"
  WindowState="Maximized"
```

But RibbonWindow becomes bigger and its bottom part hides behind taskbar.

I suppose that the only difference between window and RibbonWindows is the controlTemplate.
But i dont actually understand how can i via template place the window above the taskbar.

Any ideas how to show my RibbonWindow *above* taskbar just as normal window does?

[Link to the VS2010 project (10KiB)](http://db.tt/aRemZtU) (Microsoft Ribbon For WPF isn't included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RibbonWindow uses custom WindowChrome. That is the reason of incorrect behavior. Try this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Windows.Shell;

namespace Utils
{
    public static class WindowHelper
    {
        public static void Fullscreen(Window p_oWindow)
        {
            p_oWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            p_oWindow.Topmost = true;
            p_oWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(p_oWindow, null);
        }

        public static void UndoFullscreen(Window p_oWindow)
        {
            p_oWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            p_oWindow.Topmost = false;
            p_oWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(p_oWindow, GetChrome());
        }

        public static WindowChrome GetChrome()
        {
            WindowChrome oCustomChrome = new WindowChrome();
            oCustomChrome.CornerRadius = new System.Windows.CornerRadius(0, 0, 0, 0);
            oCustomChrome.CaptionHeight = 0;
            oCustomChrome.ResizeBorderThickness = new System.Windows.Thickness(2, 2, 2, 2);
            return oCustomChrome;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `WindowStyle`. This happens in all WPF windows when you remove the chrome. (They really optimized this feature for full-screen kiosk apps).

In order to handle maximizing your window to the correct size, you're going to need to handle it yourself. When you maximize button is clicked, you will need to get the working area of the current monitor you're on. There isn't a WPF way of doing this, but you can use the WinForms [`Screen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class.

Your maximize method would look like so:

```
// you must save the restore bounds, since we never set Window.WindowState,
// so the RestoreBounds property will get set to the maximized bounds
private System.Drawing.Rectangle restoreBounds;

private void DoMaximize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle((int)Left, (int)Top,
        (int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight));
    var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.FromRectangle(bounds);
    var area = screen.WorkingArea;

    restoreBounds = bounds; 

    Left = area.X;            
    Top = area.Y;          
    Width = area.Width;
    Height = area.Height;
}
```

Comment: Abe, I do not actually understand your solution. My taks is to make RibbonWindow's behavior similar to Window's. It should hide task bar. But currenly vice versa, taskbar is above it.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I assumed you didn't want a full screen application, as that is how it works for me in .NET 4.0 on Windows 7. What version of .NET & Windows are you using?

Comment: .NET 4.0; Windows 7, Microsoft Ribbon for WPF October 2010. Also i want to mention that simple WPF Window works just fine. Only RibbonWindow gives this bug 
I have added a URL to the project where the bug reproduces. The URL is int the question